# Searching for struct to be overwritten within a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, structure

I am working on a linked list which I have basically working but I need to extend what I currently have but I am having a problem.

I have a structure which stores outbound call legs from phone calls. I am storing these calls in a linked list which is defined as below:

```
typedef struct CallLogSearchOutboundStruct
{
    char * target;
    float duration;
    char * cleardownCause;
    BOOL allowOverwrite;
    struct CallLogSearchOutboundStruct * nextLeg;
} callLogSearchOutboundStruct;
```

I have the basic code working that I can successfully add a new outbound call onto the end of the linked list using the code below:

```
void insertOutboundLegToList(callLogSearchOutboundStruct * outboundLeg, char * target, float duration, int cleardown, BOOL overwriteFirstOutboundLegs)
{
f (outboundLeg->target == NULL)
    {
        outboundLeg->target = strdup(target);
        outboundLeg->duration = duration;
        outboundLeg->cleardownCause = strdup(setCallResult(cleardown));
        outboundLeg->allowOverwrite = FALSE;
        outboundLeg->nextLeg = NULL;
    }
    else
    {    
        if (overwriteFirstOutboundLegs == FALSE)
        {
            while (outboundLeg->nextLeg != NULL)
            {
                    outboundLeg = outboundLeg->nextLeg;
            }
        }

        if (outboundLeg->nextLeg == NULL)
        {
            outboundLeg->nextLeg = (callLogSearchOutboundStruct*)malloc(sizeof(callLogSearchOutboundStruct));
            outboundLeg = outboundLeg->nextLeg;
            outboundLeg->target = strdup(target);
            outboundLeg->duration = duration;
            outboundLeg->cleardownCause = strdup(setCallResult(cleardown));
            outboundLeg->nextLeg = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            outboundLeg->target = NULL;
            outboundLeg->duration = 0;
            outboundLeg->cleardownCause = NULL;
            outboundLeg->target = strdup(target);
            outboundLeg->duration = duration;
            outboundLeg->cleardownCause = strdup(setCallResult(cleardown));
        }
    }
}
```

This code is working however I need to modify it so that if the allowOverwrite flag is set it will then first the first outbound leg in the linked list, overwrite it and set the overwrite for the first leg to false, but all other legs in the list are set to allow overwrite.

Therefore, when a new outbound call needs to be inserted, if the overwrite first leg is set to false, then the program will need to loop through each outbound leg and check if the allow overwrite for that leg is set to true and if so overwrite that leg and then set the overwrite flag to false, then again on the next outbound leg, keep looping through until it sees allow overwrite true, overwrite and set to false, this should continue until the next leg is NULL then it just inserts the outbound leg onto the end as normal.

I think I have the base logic correct however, I seem to keep on NULL'ing the first leg, when I break from the loop so I end up with no outbound legs.

Below is how I have modified the code to try and achieve what I need.

```
if (overwriteFirstOutboundLegs == TRUE)
{
    outboundLeg->target = strdup(target);
    outboundLeg->duration = duration;
    outboundLeg->cleardownCause = strdup(setCallResult(cleardown));
    outboundLeg->allowOverwrite = FALSE;

    //Loop through existing outbound legs and set overwrite flag to TRUE
    while (outboundLeg->nextLeg != NULL)
    {
        outboundLeg = outboundLeg->nextLeg;
        outboundLeg->allowOverwrite = TRUE;
    }
    outboundLeg->nextLeg = NULL;
}
else
{
    if (outboundLeg->target == NULL)
    {
        outboundLeg->target = strdup(target);
        outboundLeg->duration = duration;
        outboundLeg->cleardownCause = strdup(setCallResult(cleardown));
        outboundLeg->allowOverwrite = FALSE;
        outboundLeg->nextLeg = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        if (outboundLeg->nextLeg == NULL)
        {
            outboundLeg->nextLeg = (callLogSearchOutboundStruct*)malloc(sizeof(callLogSearchOutboundStruct));
            outboundLeg = outboundLeg->nextLeg;
            outboundLeg->target = strdup(target);
            outboundLeg->duration = duration;
            outboundLeg->cleardownCause = strdup(setCallResult(cleardown));
            outboundLeg->allowOverwrite = FALSE;
            outboundLeg->nextLeg = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            while (outboundLeg->nextLeg != NULL)
            {
                outboundLeg = outboundLeg->nextLeg;
                if (outboundLeg->allowOverwrite == TRUE)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            outboundLeg->target = strdup(target);
            outboundLeg->duration = duration;
            outboundLeg->cleardownCause = strdup(setCallResult(cleardown));
            outboundLeg->allowOverwrite = FALSE;
            outboundLeg->nextLeg = NULL;
        }
    }
}
```

I am calling the function using the following code:

```
insertOutboundLegToList(outboundCallLegStartPtr, targetBuffer, durationBuffer, atoi(rowReport[cleardownColIndex]), overwriteFirstOutboundLegs);
```

Attached below is also a diagram showing the flow that I need for inserting a new leg.

[image: insert outbound leg flow diagram]

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Have you stepped through the code in a debugger?  That should show you what's going wrong.

Comment: Yes, I think it is related to the looping everything setting everything to true, I am overwriting what is actually stored

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it useful to explore the actual problem with a small program dedicated to the exact problem at hand.

First, I think there is an error or omission in the diagram. I do believe you wish to always clear the `overwrite` flag for the inserted or replaced leg. So, that's what the following example program does:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct node {
    struct node *next;
    int          overwrite;
    int          value;
} node;

node *insert(node **const listptr, int value, int overwrite)
{
    /* No list specified? */
    if (!listptr) {
        errno = EINVAL;
        return NULL;
    }

    /* Empty list? */
    if (!*listptr) {
        node *newnode;

        newnode = malloc(sizeof *newnode);
        if (!newnode) {
            errno = ENOMEM;
            return NULL;
        }

        newnode->next = NULL;
        newnode->value = value;
        newnode->overwrite = 0;

        *listptr = newnode;
        return newnode;
    }

    if (overwrite) {
        node *const currnode = *listptr;
        node *temp;

        /* Overwrite contents */
        currnode->value = value;
        currnode->overwrite = 0;

        /* Set overwrite flag for all nodes that follow */
        temp = currnode->next;
        while (temp) {
            temp->overwrite = 1;
            temp = temp->next;
        }

        return currnode; 

    } else {
        node **ptr = listptr; 
        node *currnode = *listptr; /* always equal to *ptr */

        /* Find the first overwritable node */
        while (currnode && !currnode->overwrite) {
            ptr = &currnode->next;
            currnode = currnode->next;
        }

        /* Found an overwritable node? */
        if (currnode) {
            currnode->value = value;
            currnode->overwrite = 0;
            return currnode;
        }

        /* Construct a new node to be appended to the list. */
        currnode = malloc(sizeof *currnode);
        if (!currnode) {
            errno = ENOMEM;
            return NULL;
        }
        currnode->next = NULL;
        currnode->value = value;
        currnode->overwrite = 0;

        /* Append to the list. */
        *ptr = currnode;
        return currnode;
    }
}

void display(const char *const header, const node *list, const char *const footer)
{
    if (header)
        fputs(header, stdout);

    if (list) {
        do {
            if (list->overwrite)
                printf("/%d", list->value);
            else
                printf("%d", list->value);

            list = list->next;

            if (list)
                putchar(' ');

        } while (list);
    } else
        fputs("(empty)", stdout);

    if (footer)
        fputs(footer, stdout);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    node *list = NULL;
    int   arg, value;
    char  dummy;

    if (argc < 2 || !strcmp(argv[1], "-h") || !strcmp(argv[1], "--help")) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [ -h | --help ]\n", argv[0]);
        fprintf(stderr, "       %s VALUE ... VALUE\n", argv[0]);
        fprintf(stderr, "Where VALUE is\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "       /INTEGER   to insert-overwrite INTEGER, or\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "       INTEGER    to insert INTEGER normally.\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    display("Initial list: ", list, ".\n");
    for (arg = 1; arg < argc; arg++) {

        if (sscanf(argv[arg], " /%d %c", &value, &dummy) == 1) {
            if (!insert(&list, value, 1)) {
                fflush(stdout);
                fprintf(stderr, "Cannot insert-overwrite %s: %s.\n", argv[arg], strerror(errno));
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            } else
                printf("Inserted %d with overwrite set:\n", value);

        } else
        if (sscanf(argv[arg], " %d %c", &value, &dummy) == 1) {
            if (!insert(&list, value, 0)) {
                fflush(stdout);
                fprintf(stderr, "Cannot insert %s: %s.\n", argv[arg], strerror(errno));
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            } else
                printf("Inserted %d:\n", value);

        } else {
            fflush(stdout);
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: Not a valid VALUE.\n", argv[arg]);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        display("\t", list, ".\n");
    }

    display("Final list: ", list, ".\n");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The idea is that you give a test sequence as command line parameters, each value being an integer (heavily simplifying your leg definitions!). Precede the value with a slash if it should be inserted with overwriting set.

You can compile the above with for example

```
gcc -W -Wall -O3 example.c -o example
```

Let's consider the test sequence `1 2 3 /4 5 /6`, meaning we insert the six first positive integers in order, but `4` and `6` with overwrite flag set (and unset for all others):

```
./example 1 2 3 /4 5 /6
```

which outputs

```
Initial list: (empty).
Inserted 1:
        1.
Inserted 2:
        1 2.
Inserted 3:
        1 2 3.
Inserted 4 with overwrite set:
        4 /2 /3.
Inserted 5:
        4 5 /3.
Inserted 6 with overwrite set:
        6 /5 /3.
Final list: 6 /5 /3.
```

After the three legs are inserted, the path is obviously just `1 2 3`, since the overwrite flag was not set for any of them, and initially the list was empty.

When `4` is inserted with overwrite set, my logic overwrites the first one, *clears the overwrite flag for it* (in contradiction to the logic description in the question), and sets the overwrite flag for the rest of the legs in the path. Therefore, the path becomes `4 /2 /3`.

When `5` is inserted, it replaces `2`, since `2` had overwrite flag set. Again, in contradiction to the logic description in the question, I *clear*  the overwrite flag for `5`. Therefore, the path becomes `4 5 /3`.

When `6` is inserted with overwrite set, it overwrites the first one. Again, I clear the overwrite flag for it, in contradiction to the logic described in the question, but set for all the rest of the legs in the path, so the path becomes `6 /5 /3`.

---

First, a minor note about the node structure: The fact that I put the next pointer at the start of the node structure is just a habit.

(It may help the compiler generate better code on some architectures, because the `next` pointer then points to the address where the `next->next` is, and that may help the compiler or the processor do simpler instructions and better prefetching patterns when doing a path walk. If you put the `next` pointer somewhere else, the `next->next` is at a fixed offset of that address; in *some* cases that *may* require an extra instruction. Does it matter in practice? Usually not, not even a single CPU cycle.)

The `insert()` function implementation should be quite straightforward:

- If the list is empty, create a new node, setting its overwrite flag to false. Done.

  Otherwise:
- If overwriting is desired, replace the first node, setting its overwrite flag to false, and the overwrite flag for all other nodes to true. Done.

  Otherwise:
- If there is a node with overwrite flag true, replace that node, resetting its overwrite flag to false. Done.

  Otherwise:
- Create a new node, setting its overwrite flag to false. Append the new node to the end of the list. Done.

The only "trick" you might wonder about, is how the `ptr` pointer is used. Simply put, it is the address where the `currnode` pointer was obtained from, essentially `currnode = *ptr`. This way, instead of checking for `currnode->next` within the loop, we just traverse the list until `currnode` becomes NULL. Then, `*ptr` refers to the `->next` pointer in the final element in the list, and we can just assign to it, to append the newly created node to the list.

I realize that this does not answer the OP's question, but that is because I don't know how to tackle the two levels of issues in the original question at the same time -- I believe there is both that logic issue (with the overwrite flags), and some kind of an implementation problem related to how the linked list is managed.

When debugging, fixing programs, or writing new programs, I always try to limit the possible sources of problems to the smallest possible set. Writing limited, simplified test cases like the above program lets me concentrate on one thing at a time, without having to switch my brain between the overall logic and the nitty-gritty details of implementation. Simply put, this is the way I'd work through the OP's problem, if it was my own code.

Now that I have an example code that implements the logic I believe is correct, and I can easily stress-test the logic, I can implement the more complex actual leg structure and leg insertion function. Knowing the logic works (and I can verify any corner case using the test program if I get any doubts), I can concentrate on the actual implementation.

Obviously, it is up to the OP now to decide which logic (their or mine) to use, and if using mine, to see how our implementations differ; I don't think the OP posted enough code (the full insertion routine) to tell where the actual problems are. At least I cannot get a full enough overview to be sure.

Anyway, hope this helps. Questions?

Comment: Thanks very much for your help much appreciated. Your code pretty much worked perfectly, I had to make some small modifications to suit my needs. Thanks again for your detailed answer

Answer (score 1):

One problem (perhaps there are others) appears that you are setting `outboundLeg->nextLeg = NULL;` before you attempt to iterate through the linked list.  So you're terminating it and therefore will never be able to set the rest to allow overwrite.  Looks like a copy-paste bug.

Edit: Another potential problem is that if `overwriteFirstOutboundLegs == FALSE` and the passed-in `outboundLeg->nextLeg != NULL` and no `outboundLeg->allowOverwrite == TRUE` is encountered in the list then the last list item will be overwritten (even though it is not flagged to allow overwrite) instead of allocating a new struct to append to the end of the list.

Comment: Thanks for noticing that. It wasn't a copy and paste bug it was a me being dumb bug. Unfortunately though this doesn't appear to be related to the issue as I am getting the same behaviour

Comment: Edited to describe another potential problem.

Comment: The outbound leg that is passed into the function would be the first outbound leg. The nextLeg is always set to NULL so if the allowOverwrite flag is false it should keep looping round until it sees outboundLeg->nextLeg is NULL and then malloc and set in there unless I am missing something somewhere

Comment: I have just updated the question with the new code though however as I found a potential issue but I still have the problem with it unfortunately

Comment: Stepping through the code again it seems to be something to do with the last else statement and the while loop I think